# Why was John Carter's earth body unaltered when he got back from Mars?

Tags: movie, john-carter

When John Carter came back from Mars, he recovered his original body, which stayed in the cave while he was over there.

We later learn that while he is on Mars, he left his Earth body in a coma-like state.

Why did his body stay unaltered while he was on Mars? Why didn't he decay or get eaten by insects and/or rodents? If his bodily functions were still active, why did he not run out of nutrients and slim down or dehydrate?

Comment: Is this about the movie or the book?

Comment: @Secko the movie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's no actual explanation in the movie but in the books John Carter is not a normal human being. He's either an immortal or at least very long-lived.

As I recall this fact doesn't make any sort of an appearance in the movie but it's also not contradicted, so I suspect that he can't (easily) starve to death and perhaps can't even be eaten by animals, or they're put off by his unnatural nature.

If his bodily functions weren't active I'd guess his apparent immortality prevents him from decaying too.

Or maybe he's just protected by the same mechanism that projects him to Mars, I can't recall if that's ever explained properly in the movie.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the medallion kept his body from any kind of harm

Comment: Welcome to SciFi. We prefer answers supported by canon, which is likely the reason for the downvote. Do you have any evidence from the movie to support this?

Comment: @Kevin What is canon? No evidence but it seems like the only logical explanation

Comment: Canon is the official body of literature backing up the story. It will include the story itself of course, but also any side-stories, books etc... that have been aproved by the original author.